# App is not visible on Google play after week

Tags: android, google-play, publish

i know there are many topics about publishing apps on Google Play, but any of them doesnt solve my problem. I published alpha version of my app week ago but it is not still visible on google play or via https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doschranky.

I also registered some alpha testers as google group but generated link for testers https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.doschranky gives 404 error.

In developer console is written that app is already published. Distribution is turn on for all countries. I am using external SDKs and billing in app.

Do you have any ideas where the problem could be?

Comment: What's the name of the app? You say you published an alpha version. I'm not sure why you think https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doschranky would work.

Comment: Everything is working now, the problem was in google group. I entered bad email for alpha testing...shame on me :)